# Problema sending json file from javascript to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

im having problems trying to send a JSON file from javascript to Laravel controller, when i press my button from the view i didnt get any response.

This is my code, i appreciate any help or suggestion, thnks.

This is the the JS code:

```
var horarios= { Lunes: arrLunes, Martes: arrMartes, Miercoles: arrMiercoles, Jueves:arrJueves, Viernes:arrViernes};

var schedule = JSON.stringify(horarios);

//console.log(schedule);
var varurl= 'http://localhost/registerEntrance';

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: varurl,
   data: {json:schedule},
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(res) {
    var message = res.mesg;
    if (message) {
        $('.flash').html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(250).fadeOut(300);
    };
}
});
```

When i press my button, doesnt happend anything. The next id the route and the controller code, the JSON file not arrive there yet.

```
Route::post('registerEntrance', array('as' => 'registerEntrance','uses' => 'CursoController@regisEnt'));

public function regisEnt(){
  if(Request::ajax()) {
    $data = Input::all();
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Thnks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get resolv my problem, i post it if someone is getting a similar inconvenience.

In my view i wasnt create a form.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['route'], 'method' => 'POST', 'id'  =>'form-name']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This part create a implicit token that is necesary in laravel for use ajax method.

My code JS was modified for getting and send the csrf token.

```
var form = $('#form-name');
var myurl = form.attr('action');
crsfToken = document.getElementsByName("_token")[0].value;

$.ajax({
        url: myurl,  
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {data:data},
        datatype: 'JSON',
        headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": crsfToken
            },

        success: function(text){
          bootbox.dialog({
            closeButton: false,
            message: "Ok!",
            title: "Perfect!!",
        },
        error: function(data){
           console.log("Error");
        }
    });
```

With this change i get arrive to my controller.

Anyway Thnks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to debug your requests? Have you checked your `storage/logs/framework/laravel.log` *(if your log is HUGE you can always delete it and re-run your request)*

Working with AJAX can get tricky when it comes to debugging your requests.
My recommendation would be

1. Open up your browser Inspector, and monitor Network Requests
2. Analyze the request you're sending.
3. Set `debug` to `true` under `config/app.php` to actually see a debug

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnks fr your soon response, i see an error with the token.    TokenMismatchException

Comment: Then you should probably take a look at your config/session.php file, as Token Mistmatch Exception is due to CSRF protection, there's a form maybe which is not sending the CSRF token.